# how to print range in an input statement in python3.x

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am a CS student who is currently very newb-ish
I just got a question that I think many experts in python from this site can answer my primitive question.

for example

```
def validNum(initialNum, endingNum):

    askNum = input("Please enter a number from initialNum to endingNum")
```

in main:

```
    validNum(1, 31)
```

but in this case, initialNum and endingNum in the prompt are string so the result would be

```
"Please enter a number from initialNum to endingNum"
```

but I want

```
"Please enter a number from 1 to 31"
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: You can simply use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.format): `input("Please enter a number from {} to {}".format(initialNum, endingNum))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.format()` to achieve your task like this example:

```
def validNum(initialNum, endingNum):
    askNum = input("Please enter a number from {0} to {1}: ".format(initialNum, endingNum))

validNum(1,31)
```

Otherwise, you can use `%` and [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to have the same result:

```
# if your input is a decimal:
askNum = input("Please enter a number from %d to %d: " % (initialNum, endingNum))

# if your input is a float:
askNum = input("Please enter a number from %f to %f: " % (initialNum, endingNum))

# or simply
askNum = input("Please enter a number from %r to %r: " % (initialNum, endingNum))

# or maybe
askNum = input("Please enter a number from %(initial)s to %(ending)s: " % {'initial': initialNum, 'ending': endingNum})
```

PS: take a look at [printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

Comment: You are amazing!

Comment: Thanks. Have a nice coding.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.6, all you need is the new f-string:

```
def validNum(initialNum, endingNum):
    askNum = input(f"Please enter a number from {initialNum} to {endingNum}")
```

Note the leading `f` and curly braces around the variables to be inserted.

Comment: Thank you for the help!!